# CloudKit and priority

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I have previously tried to implement CloudKit with a OSX/iOS app,
and because of my OCD-ness, I became very worried about prioritizing certain data between devices, and possibly losing data or reviving deleted data.

My logic is, comparing the updated datetime of the data obtained from iCloud, and locally from CoreData, with the same unique id, then prioritizing the data that has a later updated datetime.

Another issue is whether the user decides to use iCloud or not.

Is this the best way of approaching it? Do you have any suggestion, sample code, or libraries that you know that could make CloudKit easier?

Answer (score 1):

If you have this scenario, then CloudKit will raise an error:
- you read data from CloudKit
- someone else makes an update to that data
- you are trying to write an update to that data
So there is no need to to create a mechanism for that yourself.

If you want to use CloudKit in the easiest way possible then have a look at:
https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao

Comment: Hi, I've checked out your library before, as well as the sample app. Do you happen to have any examples of deleting data on one device and having a copy of it on another? How would I solve this conflict?

Comment: The best way to handle that is by using a subscription. When you delete a record, then a notification will arrive on the other device. Of course this is not instant. So there will be some time between the actual deletion and the arrived notification. In that period you still have the record on the 2nd device while it's deleted on the first. But then again, when you try to do an update on that 2nd device you will get a CloudKit error which you can handle.